# Dyn update Text field using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, dom

I have the below component. TextArea allows user to enter max of 20 characters. If user enters above 20 characters, the character count doesnot update beyond 20. So we will see only 20 characters on that input field.

```
<div>{this.state.chars_left}</div>
```

The above line of code will show the count of characters entered by user and it stops at 20 count since max value specified is 20 in this case. I need to do 2 things,

1. If user enters anything above 20. for e.g. user enters total 30 characters, then we need to display -10 in the counter field indicating that user entered 10 characters more.
2. Also, user should not be able to type special characters in this field. For e.g. "&", "#". How do i ensure user is not able to type these 2 special characters.

Can someone please guide me in above 2 scenarios.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {chars_left: 20, max_chars: 20};
  }

  handleWordCount = event => {
    const charCount = event.target.value.length;
    const maxChar = this.state.max_chars;
    const charLength = maxChar - charCount;
    this.setState({chars_left: charLength});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textArea
          rows={6}
          type="text"
          maxLength={this.state.max_chars}
          required
          onChange={this.handleWordCount}
        />
        <div>{this.state.chars_left}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('myapp'));
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="myapp"></div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with handleWordCount function? Seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. handleWordCount seems to work correctly. Tell what's wrong with the result of it. Also, you need to remove maxLength from textarea to let user typing longer text.
2. Put `event.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/#|&/gm, '')` at the end of handleWordCount.

`/#|&/gm` is a regexp rule. You can use any other rule that fits your needs.